# URL rewriting in angular with missing param?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have scenario with URL rewriting in Angular4 and need a solution. For that I need to intercept the first URL and make require changes and then redirect to new path.

Is there possibility that I could intercept that request before the route matching mechanism.

**My Scenario**

Initially I have,

```
{ path: 'page/:id', component: SomeComponent },

> http://localhost/page/<id>
```

I have to now change it to

```
{ path: 'page/:type/:id', component: SomeComponent },
```

Now, previous URL has redirect to new url (path)

```
> http://localhost/page/<id> >> http://localhost/page/<type>/<id>
```

Issue is I don't have <type> value, what will be the best approach?

One is, I will lend that previous URL with componentX (without template) and when that component runs I fetch some how the <type> and then from that componentX redirect to new path?

Comment: Do you have requirements about the URL design? I mean - do you have to make it /page/type/id or /page/id ?
If not, change the slug to /page-with-type/type/id.
Or change the order of arguments: "/page/id" and "/page/id/type".

Comment: Its a requirement! Also, we need keep the prev. url intact with the new one, is something like backward compatibility. Consider we have prev URL shared and in used. Can't go to update all of them

Comment: What I want, I can fetch the type against the id, but this is to be done before the router matching mechanism start, also redirectTo can't help me out in my situation.

Comment: Well, in this situation you'll have to think by yourself, there is no obvious and simple ways how to rebuild application and keep old urls.
I would rather analyze parameters in application and could make the decision, what to launch. There are server-side solutions as well.

Comment: @Roberc thanks, I achieved it, by answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a Resolver to your Routing could solve your problem

https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: thanks, it could be a way, can we eliminate the component some how?

Comment: thanks I achieve my desire requirement from the above solutions :-)